# eclipse not decompile rt.jar when debugging, but idea does

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to debug into com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl which can be found in rt.jar(located in jdk install path, in my case it's: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib), the problem is:

when I debug with intellj idea it auto decompile the rt.jar and I can set debugger, but:

while I use eclipse, it doesn't auto decompile rt.jar and I can't debug into it,

Clarify: I'm using JDK not JRE, I checked complie and runtime config, all are correct;

please check screenshots below

[image: debug using eclipse]

[image: debug using idea]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself after some struggling, thanks for @Andreas comments by the way,
he is right, IDEA really did a good job, nice IDE, with eclipse I have to install the **Enhanced Class Decompiler** https://ecd-plugin.github.io/ecd/, and don't forget config the 'associated file' and 'decompiler' correctly, then you can enjoy debugging into the rt.jar sourcecode